# Mathematica replaceall

Tags: replaceall

I tried to replace some expressions with a function, but some terms were not changed. 
Input:

b + 2 *a /. (b*m_ + a*n_) :> chi[m, n]

Out

2 a + b

but  if  instead of 1 I put 3*b

3*b + 2 *a /. (b*m_ + a*n_) :> chi[m, n]

The output is correct

chi[3, 2]

Weird

If I write  1.*b it works better

(1.*b + 2 *a) /. (b*m_ + a*n_) :> chi[m, n]

out

chi[1., 2]

What assumption must be done to avoid puting this point ? Yes, the simpliest way is to eliminate 1 from the pattern, but in this example I simplified the things too much only for solving the problem. My case is how to write a sum of about fifty terms of the form like that

Sqrt[Pi]*V*(m*b^2+n*a^2)^(-3/2),

where m and n are Integers and b,a,V constants

Answer (score 0):

The subexpression `b` is not matched by the pattern `b*m_`.  To see this examine the `FullForm` of `b` and of, for example, `2*b`.  Mathematica patterns match on syntactical form, not on semantics.  You and I may know that `b` is the same as `b*1` but Mathematica does not, or at least does not apply this when matching expressions to patterns.

**EDIT**

No, `1*b` won't work either, Mathematica will evaluate that to `b` before pattern-matching.  The rules for `1.0*b` are obviously different.  There is a number of ways to write a pattern to match `1*b`, the simplest is to write a separate rule such as `{b,a*n_}->chi[1,n]`.

Comment: Yes, the simpliest way is to eliminate 1 from the pattern, but in this example I simplified the things too much only for solving the problem. My case is how to write a sum of about fifty terms of the form like that  Sqrt[Pi]*V*(m*b^2+n*a^2)^(-3/2), where m and n are Integers and b,a constants